# Can the ItemAdding event be used in a Sandbox?

Tags: event-receivers, sandbox-solution

Can the ItemAdding event be used in a Sandbox?

I need to perform a task when a Item is a added/adding, it has to be synchronous (item added is async so i cant use that).

If i cant use the ItemAdding what other options do i have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible (see here too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadded(v=office.14).aspx), however you would need to be aware of some tips, such as:

- make sure you don't use any RunsAsPrivilegedUser
- debugging always by attaching to SPUCWorkerProcess

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer about using ItemAdding in Sandbox (although my guess would be yes), but another option you have is to change ItemAdded to be synchronous.

Here are a couple posts about that:

[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/unsharepoint/sharepoint-event-receivers-making-asynchronous-event-synchronous-to-avoid-save-conflict-error)

http://wineya.blogspot.com/2010/03/binding-asynchronous-event-handlers-as.html